# What effects does decreasing the opening of a chamber without reducing its volume have on air being pulled through it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm asking this here rather than on (Home Improvement)[diy.stackexchange.com] because I believe a more purely physics based answer is appropriate.

I am in the process of building a DIY exhausted spray booth for air brushing indoors. I'm a bit hung up on what the overall effect of decresing the opening of the front will be on airflow within the booth. I believe this is likely one of those problems that's so simple that my instinct is correct, but my venture into learning about static pressure makes me want to err on the side of assuming I don't know enough. I have all the health/safety bases covered, and my concern is solely on containing the paint particles so they don't end up in the room.

My booth dimensions are $24\mathrm{"w} \times 21\mathrm{"h} \times 19\mathrm{"d}$ for a total of **5.54 ft<sup>3</sup>** and a **"face" of 3.5 ft<sup>2</sup>**. It is a normal box shape. Based on my research of various booths on the market, and spec sheets from various spray booth fan manufacturers, a target "face velocity" of **90 Linear Feet per Minute (LFM)** is sufficient to prevent particles from escaping the opening of the booth.

Simple math says the face dimensions multiplied by desired face velocity gets you the cubic feet per minute needed to hit the target speed:

$3.5\mathrm{ft^2} \times 90\mathrm{ft/m} = 315\mathrm{ft^3}$

That's high for most reasonably sized extraction fans to hit. My hypothesis is that I can decrease the area of the face to reduce the required CFM to hit the 90 LFM I'm after. Even taking just 2" off the vertical gives me this:

$3.17\mathrm{ft^2} \times 90\mathrm{ft/m} = 285\mathrm{ft^3}$

That puts this within the realm of the size and noise level desired for a fan. I can reduce it more since I oversized the booth for unpowered use outside as well.

But I'm left wondering about the dynamics of the airflow inside the chamber now that it's not a straight open duct shape to the exhaust duct. I have very limited knowledge of fluid dynamics but I used to drive a pickup truck, and my gut is telling me this will create a truck bed style pocket of turbulence. Essentially a portion of the air at the ceiling of the booth rolling back on itself in a loop.

My gut also tells me that even if this does happen, it will not prevent the booth from meeting my primary goal. So long as the air moving through the booth is pulled into it by the extraction fan rather than blown in from outside (air brush not withstanding), the booth will be in an overall negative pressure state.

Of course if there are any particles trapped in a pocket of air they could go anywhere when the fan is turned off, but I have a cover for the opening to prevent dust from settling on drying paint.

Is the math for reducing the CFM requirement really that simple given that I'm not actually decreasing the volume of the chamber? It feels like a cheat. And is there anything major that I'm missing in the effects it will have on the airflow within the booth?